# PHP/JS: Summarize ajax requests

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

because I don't want to create a new ajax file for every subpage, I want to summarize all of my ajax request to CREATE, UPDATE and DELETE.

Therefore I named all of my inputs and selects like 'input_*' and 'select_*' and add the table name with &area. The * stands for the row in the MySQL table.

Then I do the ajax request with (for example create):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/ajax/ajax.create.php",
    data: $('#form_*').serialize() + "&area=customers",
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

1. How can I process the data in PHP to get an array with all the values without 'input_' and 'select_' (for example: name=>name, email=>email, ...)
2. Is this a good and safe way to process all of my ajax requests?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `because I don't want to create a new ajax file for every subpage` you can add parameters to the path and then interpret them on the server-side. So your URL can look something like `php/ajax/customers/create` - where *customers* is the parameter. More generally your path would can be `php/ajax/{page}/{action}` or just using GET parameters `php/ajax?page={page}&action={action}` or anything else. These can all hit the same endpoint on the server and you can decide what to do based on the parameters used.

Answer (score 0):

You need one `PHP` and in your ajax request, tell PHP what you are sending.
In your `PHP` use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)  to check the current data that is being send.

For example in PHP

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    // delete post data
} elseif (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    // update post data
} elseif (isset($_POST['create'])) {
    // create data here
} elseif ....
```

In your javascript

```
$('#delete').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/ajax/ajax_file.php",
        data: $('#deleteForm').serialize() + '&' + $.param({delete: true}),
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
})

$('#create').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/ajax/ajax_file.php",
        data: $('#createForm').serialize() + '&' + $.param({create: true}),
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
})

$('#update').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/ajax/ajax_file.php",
        data: $('#updateForm').serialize() + '&' + $.param({update: true}),
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
})
```

All this request use the same file, you just need to check which data is being send with `isset()` in your PHP. You can also use hidden inputs in your form and remove `$.param()`, like `<input type="text" name="delete" value="delete" hidden>`